How Does This Antique Television Circuit Work?
I'm trying to learn tube electronics, specifically for antique television applications. The vertical deflection circuit in the 1949 Motorola VT73 Chassis TS-4J confuses me. I can't understand how this circuit is supposed to produce a sawtooth voltage waveform. I've tried building the circuit in LTSpice using vacuum tube models, but the circuit does nothing. The entire schematic is listed, the circuit in question being boxed in red with inputs and outputs labeled.


Electrostatic deflection! That's ancient. It has to generate a differential output sawtooth. The asymmetry comes from the low plate resistance of the oscillator tube vs. the ~5MΩ the 100nF capacitor charges from. Why don't you post your LTspice netlist, maybe someone can get it twitching.

What sync pulse are you applying to the circuit?

I attempted to model it in Falstad, but the sim would not converge (probably an issue with startup sequence and an imperfect model.) You're welcome to try it, here: https://tinyurl.com/222k3as3

You may need to get better SPICE models for your tubes. Try here: https://www.normankoren.com/Audio/Tubemodspice_article.html

I had great fun with this circuit, and, yes, it somehow works.
I divided all supply voltages and resistor values by 10 and multiplied all capacitor values by 10 to translate this into a (not very realistic) JFET environment. The frequency arrived at 10 Hz and the vertical retrace is too long. If you want to play with it, you may adjust this.
The original circuit seams magically to work without a negative gate bias, this didn't work with the JFETs.
Well, I admit, you would not see the newsticker at the bottom, but it would be good enough for a daily soup.
The circuit needs an initial edge to start, but then continues to oscillate.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

That's clever - a JFET is a reasonable model for a tube.

@greybeard yes, funny typo
